# Flow of recursion in python roman to arabic

Tags: python, recursion

So I just solved the last quiz on recursion on codeacademy. But while I was trying to understand the flow of execution of this code on pythontutor.org, I just couldnt follow the flow of this code.

```
def rval(letr):
     if(letr=='I'):
         return 1
     elif(letr=='V'):
         return 5
     elif(letr=='X'):
         return 10
     elif(letr=='L'):
         return 50
     elif(letr=='C'):
         return 100
     elif(letr=='D'):
         return 500
     elif(letr=='M'):
         return 1000
     else:
         return "error"


def arabic(n):
     if len(n)==0:
         return 0
     elif len(n)==1:
         return rval(n)
     elif len(n)==2:
         if rval(n[0])>rval(n[1]):
             return rval(n[0])+rval(n[1])
         else:
             return rval(n[1])-rval(n[0])
     else:
         return arabic(n[len(n)-2:])+arabic(n[:len(n)-2])

arabic('DXCVI')
```

======PROBLEM FACED======

My question is this -- 
Suppose I run `arabic('DXCVI')`, then how does this line `arabic(n[len(n)-2:])+arabic(n[:len(n)-2])`  get executed

Do both `arabic(n[len(n)-2:])` & `arabic(n[:len(n)-2])` start getting executed simultaneously or does the second term wait until the first is done/returns a value ?

Comment: You need to read [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195385/understanding-stack-frame-of-function-call-in-c-c). Another way to see which executes first is to implement the `fibonacci series` using recursion and no memoisation and using print statements, this should tell you which function call excutes first

Comment: Thanks that was imformative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `arabic(n[len(n)-2:])` (the left part) is executed, then `arabic(n[:len(n)-2])` (the right part) is executed.

Remember that the first part may also have recursive calls, so the second one must wait until it returns a value to get executed.

Answer (score 1):

The left part  `arabic(n[len(n)-2:])` is always called first. An easy way to find this out is to put a `print` statement in your `arabic(n)` function.

Try something like this:

```
def arabic(n):
    print n
    if len(n)==0:
        return 0
    elif len(n)==1:
        return rval(n)
    elif len(n)==2:
    # more code
```

Which would output this:

```
DXCVI
VI
DXC
XC
D
```

Proving that the left side, `arabic(n[len(n)-2:])`, gets called before `+arabic(n[:len(n)-2])`.